# DNA polymerase in PCR (polymerase chain reaction)

Tags: molecular-biology, pcr, polymerase

Can the DNA polymerase in PCR (polymerase chain reaction) recognize both DNA and RNA for use as a template?

I want to know is it possible if my primers bind to contaminant RNA and then any DNA polymerase like Taq DNA polymerase use this strand as the template for elongation?

Comment: Do you want to know if a PCR reaction is possible with different enzymes for DNA and RNA?

Comment: Hi Chris, I want to know is it possible if my primers bind to an contaminant RNA and then any DNA polymerase like Taq DNA polymerase use this strand as template to elongation and continue reaction?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer, please roll this back, if this is not ok for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this does not happen, as the DNA polymerases used for PCR are DNA dependent. This means that they only synthesize DNA when it is bound to DNA. Even if your primers bind to the RNA, the polymerase will not starting new strands here. To use RNA as a template for PCR you first need to reverse transcribe it.

Comment: And one more that may 3-HO end of binded nocleotide contaminant(small crashed RNA ) lead to give unwanted fragment?

Comment: @M007 I don't get your second question, sorry.